# uBlock, block all third party script when visiting a certain domain

Tags: firefox, adblock, ublock-origin, ublock

With uBlock Origin on Firefox, I am trying to block all third-party scripts called from a specific first-party page.

For example: visiting a page of example.com, I want that every external script gets blocked.

I am following this great [ublock origin syntax guide](https://adguard.com/kb/it/general/ad-filtering/create-own-filters/), and this and [this other guide](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax).

I tried

```
||example.com*$script,third-party
```

and even (that should block all third parties, even images)

```
||example.com*$third-party
```

and I tried for specific third-party domain

```
||example.com^$script,third-party,domain=disqus.com
```

I saved the custom rules, but refreshing the page, and inspecting the network panel, none of the custom rules seems to work.

Comment: These should work if they are added to _My filters_ (these are filters, not rules). Reasons why they may not work: Is My filters list enabled? Reload the page with forcing a browser cache bypass (press Ctrl while clicking reload), it's often the reason of such behavior, as the browser bypasses content blockers for resources held in its short-term memory-based cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. Don't know why, but apparently the rule won't work from **My Filters** uBlock Origin panel, but it works on **My Rules** panel, where I set

```
example.com * 3p-script block
```

[image]

Btw I discovered that uBlock Origin has an advanced mode:
from addon 
*settings > options > I am an advanced user*

if you enabled it, you can use [GUI dynamic filtering](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dynamic-filtering:-quick-guide), now if you open the uBlock addon popup on a webpage, there is a sidebar with a very handy **3rd-party scripts** toggle, you then could disable then on every website (1) or only on the current website (2)
[image]